# DataGridView reorder columns when filled with data

Tags: c#

In a VS2010 program, I have a DataGridView with custom Columns ( not editables ). When I start the GUI, columns are shown in the order I put them; the problem is that when the program starts filling them, columns are reordered in some strange way, and I can't figure out why ( i disable the manual reordering and resizing option).
How can I force the columns to stay in the order I've decided?

Comment: The "strange" reordering is probably the same as your underlying data table. If that is the case, the control is likely auto-generating default columns and replacing your custom ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if AutoGenerateColumns is set to true put it to false in the properties of your DataGridView. How does it work then?

Comment: In the DataGridView properties there's no field named "AutoGenerateColumns" ; by the way, the program doesn't add any column, it just reorders the ones I've added to it.

Comment: The `AutoGenerateColumns` property is not visible in the Form Designer, but does exist as a class member. You can explicitly disable it in your code. After InitializeComponent() is usually a good place, but any time before the control is drawn should work.

Yet another problem with inheriting a DataGridView control is that if the base control does not have columns defined, the AutoGenerateColumns remains true; if you assign your columns in a subclassed control, your definitions are clobbered when the control auto-generates from the data source, if you don't disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your DTG is creating collumns automatically.

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn.displayindex.aspx

I hope this will be helpfull for U

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and thanks for taking your time to answer a question. Unfortunately your answer only includes a link, something which is discouraged on SO because links can become invalid or dead. Please edit your post to include what you think is most helpful in answering the question and keep the link as a reference for anyone who wants further information.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the Grid Columns DisplayIndex propert in ascending order only i.e. 1,2,3,4 etc.
In case if your grid conatins visible and invisible columns, you must set the grid DisplayIndex for the invisible columns as well.